# How do I remove the space remaining after using string.Replace("-", "")

Tags: c#, .net

I've converted a PDF document to text using PDFBox. However, many words are split over 2-lines with dashes.

For example, the word `Others` changes to `Oth-ers`, the word `becoming` changes to `be-coming`, etc.

If I use `string.Replace` to replace the "-" with an empty string, it leaves the word separated with a space between.

Is there a way in C# to remove the dash in the middle of a word and concatenate the sections of the word into one word again?

Comment: If the word is `Oth-ers` and you replace `"-"` with `""`, you're going to get `Others`, no space.

Comment: I've not come across this problem where using `""` doesn't just remove the character and not leave a space (according to your title that's what's happening). However, it could be something to do with the PDF conversion so does it work if you use null instead? `String.Replace("-", null);`

Comment: Are you using `Replace(char, char)` or `Replace(string, string)`? You'll need to be using the latter to ensure you can replace with an empty string, as opposed to the space char.

Comment: If there is still a space between words, I'd wager you're looking at some weird non standard combo - try looking at the bytes of the string using Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes

Comment: I suspect given he is looking at wrapping words he also has a CRLF in there.

Comment: @JerKimball Or just looking at the `char`s, that would work the same and would be simpler.

Comment: There's probably a setting in PDFBox to not break words. Have you looked?

Comment: @svick hush you and your logic! :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this unit test and the dash was removed correctly.

```
[TestMethod]
public void ReplaceDashByEmptyString()
{
    string othersWithDash = "Oth-ers";

    string othersWithoutDash = othersWithDash.Replace("-", string.Empty);

    Assert.AreEqual("Others", othersWithoutDash);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) for this.

```
var text =@"Others Oth-ers";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"\w+\-\w+");
foreach(Match dashMatch in matches)
{
    text = Regex.Replace(text, Regex.Escape(dashMatch.Value), dashMatch.Value.Replace("-", string.Empty));
}    
//Then you can have your new test variable
```

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: If you write RegEx that are difficult to read into your code collection, I guess you'll end up with these problem xD